# Push content of the object to array instead of the name of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an empty object, and i want to push a key value pair to the array.

```
required.forEach(function(value){
     if(value){
        var tempVal = "event_info.schema." + value;


        // console.log(tempVal);
        var row = {tempVal: [properties[value]['type']]};


     }
});
```

when I console.log(row) it shows

```
{ tempVal: [ 'string' ] }
```

However I want it to be the content of tempVal instead of "tempVal"

i.e. if `tempVal = "name"`, I want row to be `{ name : ['string']}`.  How can I achieve this? 
I have tried tempVal.eval() but that is an error. Can you point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects can also be indexed with brackets.

```
tempVal = 'someString';
var obj = {};
obj[tempVal] = ['myArrayOfOneString'];
console.log(obj) // {'someString': ['myArrayOfOneString']}
```

Note that `obj.something` is equivalent to `object['something']`

Comment: var obj = {[tempVal]:['myArrayOfOneString']} ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use array notation to set the property dynamically, like this:

```
var row = {};
row[tempVal] = [properties[value]['type']];
```

EDIT: as a commenter pointed out, you can condense this to one line (ES6 only):

```
var row = {[tempVal]: [properties[value]['type']]}
```

Comment: var row = {[tempVal]: [properties[value]['type']]} ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**This should do what you are looking for:**

```js
var
    event_info = {
        schema: {
            name: "Yoda",
            age: "150"
        }
    },
    properties = {
        name: {type: "male"},
        age: {type: "old"}
    }
//
var value = "name";
//
var tempVal = event_info.schema[value];

var row = {};
row[tempVal] = [properties[value]['type']];

console.log("tempVal:", tempVal);
console.log("row:", row);
console.log("row 'Yoda':", row["Yoda"]);
```

Comment: or even shorter as per ES6: var row = {[tempVal]: [properties[value]['type']]};

Comment: @HolgerWill yepp!